# AWS Athena Create Table with source string

Tags: amazon-athena

Is there a way to create one table based on json string and keep this whole json string as one column.

for example: I have one file contains two rows, like below

```
{"name": "Tommy", "Age": 16} 
{"name": "Will", "Age": 20}
```

What I want is to create one table that contains 3 columns, `[name, age, org_string]`. When I select `org_string` from this table, it just returns the original string.

Is that possible, and how could I do that?

Or how to create table with only two columns `[name, age]`, but in the query result contains `org_string`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create table as -

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_name`(
  `org_string` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/location/'
```

Query data from table as -

```sql
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(org_string, '$.name') as name,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(org_string, '$.Age') as age,
org_string
from table_name
```